# Xdebug 3.2 breakpoints not working in Laradock with VS Code

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laradock

I'm facing an issue with Xdebug 3.2 breakpoints not working in my Laravel project running in Laradock when using VS Code as the IDE. Please note that I am using Xdebug version 3.2.

Here are the details of my setup:

1. I have installed Xdebug 3.2 in Laradock by modifying the following values in the Laradock `.env` file:

```
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG=true
WORKSPACE_XDEBUG_PORT=9003
PHP_FPM_XDEBUG_PORT=9003
```

2. My Laravel project is located at the same level as the Laradock project. I'm using the Laradock configurations for several projects.
3. In my Laravel project, I have created a `launch.json` file in VS Code with the following configuration:

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
           "type": "php",
           "request": "launch",
           "port": 9003
       }
   ]
}
```

4. I have placed a breakpoint in the welcome view in the `web.php` file of my Laravel project. I have ensured that the code is going through that page by echoing `phpinfo()`, which correctly shows that I'm using Xdebug 3.2.
5. Inside the Docker container, I made changes to the `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini` file with the following values:

```
; NOTE: The actual debug.so extension is NOT SET HERE but rather (/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini)

xdebug.client_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey=vsc

xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.cli_color=1
; xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
; xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

6. I have tried restarting the PHP-FPM and web server services in Laradock after making the configuration changes, but the issue persists.
7. I have also cleared the Laravel application cache by running `php artisan cache:clear` to ensure there are no caching issues.
8. Of course, I have started the debugger in VSCode.

Despite following all these steps, the Xdebug 3.2 breakpoints are not working in this setup.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you installed the xdebug extension in your VSCode? `xdebug.idekey=vsc` <<== you sure it's just `vsc`? `Inside the Docker container, I made changes to the...`, so ... you have your `xdebug.ini` in your laradock folders. That .ini gets loaded and reconfigured through your Dockerfile. xdebug gets turned on through a bash script. Why would you manually make those changes?

Comment: Yes, I have installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug

Comment: I changed the ```xdebug.ini``` in an act of desperation, but it changes nothing at all, as you point out.